# Why can not modify a value in a dataframe by using boolean mask ?

Tags: python, dataframe

For example, I want to change 'Republic of Korea' in 'Country' column to 'South Korea', but looks like 'Republic of Korea' still remains there:

> ```
> df[df['Country'] == 'Republic of Korea']['Country'] = 'South Korea'
> df[df['Country'] == 'Republic of Korea']['Country']
>
>
> 164    Republic of Korea
> Name: Country, dtype: object
> ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are working on a [copy (slice) of original dataframe](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy). Try using [dataframe.loc](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.18.1/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html)

```
df.loc[df['Country'] == 'Republic of Korea', 'Country'] = 'South Korea'
```

Also there should have been a warning when you run the code:

> A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
>
> Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

Comment: Tried "df.loc[df['Country'] == 'Republic of Korea', 'Country'] = 'South Korea'" as suggested but the country name still keeps unchanged ...

Comment: @BingQian you use df.loc as `[row_indexer, col_indexer]` **not as** `[row_indexer][col_indexer]` I don't think it would work as latter (since you copy it again with the [col_indexer]).